# In a pulley system involving two particles attached to the ends of a light, inextensible string...

Tags: classical-mechanics

if one particle descends by a certain distance, will the other particle ascend by the same distance?

For example, if the two particles are hanging next to eachother, both 2 metres above the ground. If one of the particles descends by 2 metres, would the other particle also ascend by 2 metres.

Comment: Obviously yes! But where comes from your doubt? Maybe there are many pulleys connected by the string?

Comment: I had done a question where two particles are both two metres above the ground. They asked for the greatest height a particle, Q,  reaches above the ground after the other particle, P,  descends by 2 metres and hits the ground. I found what further distance Q goes up by after P strikes the ground (some value 'x'). Since they asked Q's greatest height reached above the ground, I added that value (x) to 2 and then 2 again for my final answer as it rises two metres before P strikes the grond and is already 2 metres above the ground. However, the book added 2 to the value (x) only once...